# Why threejs render too slow this html file?

Tags: javascript, three.js

Hello I tried a threejs script trying to make a game like minecraft. But I failed at that. This is my HTML file:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="https://i.ibb.co/gzfRWD5/minecraft-2-icon.png">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/108/three.js"></script>
    <script src="../../scripts/perlin.js"></script>
    <script src="../../scripts/localStorageDB.js"></script>
    <title>Minecraft 2 - V13 (Pre-Alpha)</title>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark">
      <div id="linkslot_214396"><script src="https://linkslot.ru/bancode.php?id=214396" async></script></div>
      <a class="navbar-brand"href="#">
        Options:
        <input class="btn btn-primary" type="button" value="Show"id="showMenu">
        <input class="btn btn-danger" type="button" value="Hide"id="hideMenu">
      </a>
      <div id="linkslot_214398"><script src="https://linkslot.ru/bancode.php?id=214398" async></script></div>
    </nav>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark"id="optionsNav"style="position:absolute;top:-9999px">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        Render distance:
        <input class="form-control" id="render_distance_input" placeholder="Enter here.">
        <input class="btn btn-primary" type="button" value="increase"id="increaseRender">
        <input class="btn btn-danger" type="button" value="decrease"id="decreaseRender">
      </a>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        Mouse sensivity:
        <input class="form-control" id="mouse_sensivity_input" placeholder="Enter here.">
        <input class="btn btn-primary" type="button" value="increase"id="increaseSensivity">
        <input class="btn btn-danger" type="button" value="decrease"id="decreaseSensivity">
      </a>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        Camera field of view:
        <input class="form-control" id="fov_input" placeholder="Enter here.">
        <input class="btn btn-primary" type="button" value="increase"id="increaseField">
        <input class="btn btn-danger" type="button" value="decrease"id="decreaseField">
      </a>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        Fog distance with respect the render distance:
        <input class="form-control" id="fog_input" placeholder="Enter here.">
        <input class="btn btn-primary" type="button" value="increase"id="increaseFog">
        <input class="btn btn-danger" type="button" value="decrease"id="decreaseFog">
      </a>
    </nav>
    <script>
    setTimeout(()=>{
      localStorage.clear()
      w=Math.floor(Math.random()*1000000)
      cube={}
      xa=0
      ya=0
      m=[]
      k=[]
      render_distance_input.value=4
      mouse_sensivity_input.value=1
      fov_input.value=50
      fog_input.value=0
      onmousemove=(event)=>{
        mouseX=event.clientX
        mouseY=event.clientY
        if(document.pointerLockElement===renderer.domElement||
        document.mozPointerLockElement===renderer.domElement){
          xa-=0.01*event.movementX*mouse_sensivity_input.value
          if(-1.5<ya&&0<event.movementY){
            ya-=0.01*event.movementY*mouse_sensivity_input.value
          }
          if(ya<1.5&&event.movementY<0){
            ya-=0.01*event.movementY*mouse_sensivity_input.value
          }
        }
      }
      onmousedown=onmouseup=(e)=>{
        m[e.button]=e.type=="mousedown"
        if(
          document.pointerLockElement===renderer.domElement
          ||
          document.mozPointerLockElement===renderer.domElement
        ){
        }else{
          if(200<mouseY&&optionsNav.style.top=="-9999px"){
            renderer.domElement.requestPointerLock()
          }
        }
      }
      onkeydown=onkeyup=(e)=>{k[e.keyCode]=e.type=="keydown"}
      box=new THREE.BoxGeometry(1,1,1)
      box_texture=new THREE.TextureLoader().load("../../images/textures/box.jpg")
      brick_texture=new THREE.TextureLoader().load("../../images/textures/brick.jpg")
      stone_texture=new THREE.TextureLoader().load("../../images/textures/stone.jpg")
      leaves_texture=new THREE.TextureLoader().load("../../images/textures/leaves.jpg")
      dirt_texture=new THREE.TextureLoader().load("../../images/textures/dirt.jpg")
      trunk_texture=new THREE.TextureLoader().load("../../images/textures/trunk.jpg")
      grass_texture=new THREE.TextureLoader().load("../../images/textures/grass.jpg")
      limestone_texture=new THREE.TextureLoader().load("../../images/textures/limestone.jpg")
      granite_texture=new THREE.TextureLoader().load("../../images/textures/granite.png")
      magma_texture=new THREE.TextureLoader().load("../../images/textures/magma.jpg")
      box_material=new THREE.MeshPhysicalMaterial({map:box_texture})
      bricks_material=new THREE.MeshPhysicalMaterial({map:brick_texture})
      stone_material=new THREE.MeshPhysicalMaterial({map:stone_texture})
      leaves_material=new THREE.MeshPhysicalMaterial({map:leaves_texture})
      dirt_material=new THREE.MeshPhysicalMaterial({map:dirt_texture})
      trunk_material=new THREE.MeshPhysicalMaterial({map:trunk_texture})
      grass_material=new THREE.MeshPhysicalMaterial({map:grass_texture})
      limestone_material=new THREE.MeshPhysicalMaterial({map:limestone_texture})
      granite_material=new THREE.MeshPhysicalMaterial({map:granite_texture})
      magma_material=new THREE.MeshPhysicalMaterial({map:magma_texture})
      document.body.style.margin=0
      renderer=new THREE.WebGLRenderer()
      document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement)
      renderer.domElement.requestPointerLock=renderer.domElement.requestPointerLock||renderer.domElement.mozRequestPointerLock
      camera=new THREE.PerspectiveCamera()
      camera.xs=0
      camera.ys=0
      camera.zs=0
      camera.near=0.1
      camera.far=10000
      seed=Math.floor(Math.random()*Math.pow(10,10))
      scene=new THREE.Scene()
      render()
      directionalLight=new THREE.DirectionalLight("rgb(255,255,255)",1)
      scene.add(directionalLight)
      dlya=0.5
      directionalLight.castShadow=true
      directionalLight.receiveShadow=true
      directionalLight.position.set(0,1,0)
      directionalLight.target.position.set(0,0,0)
      scene.background=new THREE.Color("rgb(0,150,250)")
      fog1=new THREE.Fog("rgb(0,150,250)",0.01,100)
      scene.fog=fog1
      light=new THREE.HemisphereLight("rgb(255,255,255)","rgb(100,100,100)",0.25)
      scene.add(light)
      camera.position.set(0,noise.simplex2(seed,0)*100+5,0)
      all=new THREE.Geometry()
      all_figure=new THREE.Mesh(all)
      scene.add(all_figure)
    },1)
    g=(x,y,z,obj)=>{
      i1=Math.random()
      if(obj=="box"){
        cube[i1]=new THREE.Mesh(box,box_material)
      }
      if(obj=="leaves"){
        cube[i1]=new THREE.Mesh(box,leaves_material)
      }
      if(obj=="brick"){
        cube[i1]=new THREE.Mesh(box,bricks_material)
      }
      if(obj=="stone"){
        cube[i1]=new THREE.Mesh(box,stone_material)
      }
      if(obj=="dirt"){
        cube[i1]=new THREE.Mesh(box,dirt_material)
      }
      if(obj=="grass"){
        cube[i1]=new THREE.Mesh(box,grass_material)
      }
      if(obj=="trunk"){
        cube[i1]=new THREE.Mesh(box,trunk_material)
      }
      if(obj=="limestone"){
        cube[i1]=new THREE.Mesh(box,limestone_material)
      }
      if(obj=="granite"){
        cube[i1]=new THREE.Mesh(box,granite_material)
      }
      if(obj=="magma"){
        cube[i1]=new THREE.Mesh(box,magma_material)
      }
      cube[i1].position.set(x,y,z)
      scene.add(cube[i1])
    }
    distance_to_object=(x,y,z,x2,y2,z2)=>{
      return Math.pow(((x-x2)*(x-x2)+(y-y2)*(y-y2)+(z-z2)*(z-z2)),0.5)
    }
    check_into_object=(x,y,z,x2,y2,z2)=>{
      if(
        (x-0.4<x2+0.4&&x+0.4>x2-0.4)
        &&
        (y-0.4<y2+0.4&&y+0.4>y2-0.4)
        &&
        (z-0.4<z2+0.4&&z+0.4>z2-0.4)
      ){
        return true
      }else{
        return false
      }
    }
    check_into_square=(x,y,z,x2,y2,z2,r)=>{
      if(
        (x-r<x2+r&&x+r>x2-r)
        &&
        (y-r<y2+r&&y+r>y2-r)
        &&
        (z-r<z2+r&&z+r>z2-r)
      ){
        return true
      }else{
        return false
      }
    }
    check_object=(x,y,z)=>{
      checked=false
      for(i1 in cube){
        if(check_into_object(x,y,z,cube[i1].position.x,cube[i1].position.y,cube[i1].position.z)){
          checked=true
        }
      }
      return checked
    }
    check_id=(x,y,z)=>{
      id=0
      for(i1 in cube){
        if(check_into_object(x,y,z,cube[i1].position.x,cube[i1].position.y,cube[i1].position.z)){
          id=i1
        }
      }
      return id
    }
    
    //DON'T USE!!!
    //render_distance_input.value=4
    //mouse_sensivity_input.value=1
    //fov_input.value=50
    
    increaseRender.onclick=()=>{
      render_distance_input.value=eval(eval(render_distance_input.value)+1)
    }
    decreaseRender.onclick=()=>{
      render_distance_input.value=eval(eval(render_distance_input.value)-1)
    }
    
    increaseSensivity.onclick=()=>{
      mouse_sensivity_input.value=eval(eval(mouse_sensivity_input.value)+0.1)
      mouse_sensivity_input.value=Math.floor(mouse_sensivity_input.value*10)/10
    }
    decreaseSensivity.onclick=()=>{
      mouse_sensivity_input.value=eval(eval(mouse_sensivity_input.value)-0.1)
      mouse_sensivity_input.value=Math.floor(mouse_sensivity_input.value*10)/10
    }
    
    increaseField.onclick=()=>{
      fov_input.value.value=eval(eval(fov_input.value)+1)
    }
    decreaseField.onclick=()=>{
      fov_input.value.value=eval(eval(fov_input.value)-1)
    }
    
    showMenu.onclick=()=>{
      optionsNav.style.top=eval(64+8)+"px"
    }
    hideMenu.onclick=()=>{
      optionsNav.style.top="-9999px"
    }
    
    increaseFog.onclick=()=>{
      fog_input.value=eval(eval(fog_input.value)+1)
    }
    decreaseFog.onclick=()=>{
      fog_input.value=eval(eval(fog_input.value)-1)
    }
    
    render=()=>{
      //This sinchronize the scene.
      renderer.shadowMap.enabled=true
      renderer.shadowMap.type=THREE.BasicShadowMap
      renderer.setSize(innerWidth,innerHeight-128)
      camera.aspect=innerWidth/(innerHeight-128)
      camera.updateProjectionMatrix()
      requestAnimationFrame(render)
      renderer.render(scene,camera)
      //This update the player.
      camera.fov=fov_input.value
      if(-1.5>ya){ya=-1.5}
      if(1.5<ya){ya=1.5}
      camera.position.x+=camera.xs
      camera.position.y+=camera.ys
      camera.position.z+=camera.zs
      camera.xs*=7/8
      //camera.ys*=7/8
      camera.zs*=7/8
      if(-0.2<camera.ys){camera.ys-=0.01}
      camera.lookAt(
        camera.position.x+Math.sin(xa)*Math.cos(ya),
        camera.position.y+Math.sin(ya),
        camera.position.z+Math.cos(xa)*Math.cos(ya)
      )
      //Walk.
      if(k[65]){
        camera.xs+=0.005*Math.cos(xa)
        camera.zs-=0.005*Math.sin(xa)
      }
      if(k[87]){
        camera.xs+=0.005*Math.sin(xa)
        camera.zs+=0.005*Math.cos(xa)
      }
      if(k[68]){
        camera.xs-=0.005*Math.cos(xa)
        camera.zs+=0.005*Math.sin(xa)
      }
      if(k[83]){
        camera.xs-=0.005*Math.sin(xa)
        camera.zs-=0.005*Math.cos(xa)
      }
      //Jump.
      if(k[32]){
        //camera.ys+=0.005
        if(check_object(camera.position.x,camera.position.y-1.6,camera.position.z)){camera.ys=0.15}
      }
      if(k[88]){
        //camera.ys-=0.005
      }
      //This makes the solid collision.
      if(
        check_object(camera.position.x+camera.xs,camera.position.y-0.5,camera.position.z)
        ||
        check_object(camera.position.x+camera.xs,camera.position.y-1.5,camera.position.z)
      ){
        camera.xs=0
      }
      if(
        check_object(camera.position.x,camera.position.y+camera.ys-0.5,camera.position.z)
        ||
        check_object(camera.position.x,camera.position.y+camera.ys-1.5,camera.position.z)
      ){
        camera.ys=0
      }
      if(
        check_object(camera.position.x,camera.position.y-0.5,camera.position.z+camera.zs)
        ||
        check_object(camera.position.x,camera.position.y-1.5,camera.position.z+camera.zs)
      ){
        camera.zs=0
      }
      //This updates the render distance properties.
      render_distance=Math.floor(eval(render_distance_input.value))
      try{
        fog1.far=eval(render_distance+eval(fog_input.value)-1.5)
      }catch(e){}
      fixed_x=Math.floor(camera.position.x)
      fixed_y=Math.floor(camera.position.y)
      fixed_z=Math.floor(camera.position.z)
      //Player click.
      if(
        m[0]&&
        document.pointerLockElement===renderer.domElement||
        document.mozPointerLockElement===renderer.domElement
      ){
        for(i=0;i<2;i+=0.1){
          save(
            w+
            "x"+Math.floor(0.5+camera.position.x+Math.sin(xa)*Math.cos(ya)*i)+
            "y"+Math.floor(0.5+camera.position.y+Math.sin(ya)*i)+
            "z"+Math.floor(0.5+camera.position.z+Math.cos(xa)*Math.cos(ya)*i)
          ,0)
        }
      }
    }
    
    setInterval(()=>{
      //This updates the generation.
      for(x=fixed_x-render_distance;x<fixed_x+render_distance;x++){
        for(y=fixed_y-render_distance;y<fixed_y+render_distance;y++){
          for(z=fixed_z-render_distance;z<fixed_z+render_distance;z++){
            if(read(w+"x"+x+"y"+y+"z"+z)=="NaN"||read(w+"x"+x+"y"+y+"z"+z)==null){
              //If is into the render distance and there is not data in the database.
              val=0
              surface=noise.simplex2(x/500+seed,z/500)*100
              //Layer of magma.
              if(surface-150<y&&y<surface-100){
                val=10
              }
              //Second layer of granite & magma.
              if(surface-125<y&&y<surface-100){
                if(Math.random()<0.5){
                  val=9
                }else{
                  val=10
                }
              }
              //Second layer of granite & magma.
              if(surface-100<y&&y<surface-75){
                if(Math.random()<0.75){
                  val=9
                }else{
                  val=10
                }
              }
              //First layer of granite & magma.
              if(surface-75<y&&y<surface-50){
                if(Math.random()<0.9){
                  val=9
                }else{
                  val=10
                }
              }
              //Layer of granite.
              if(surface-50<y&&y<surface-25){val=9}
              //Layer of limestone and granite.
              if(surface-25<y&&y<surface-20){
                if(Math.random()<0.5){
                  val=9
                }else{
                  val=8
                }
              }
              //Layer of limestone.
              if(surface-20<y&&y<surface-10){val=8}
              //Layer of dirt and limestone.
              if(surface-10<y&&y<surface-5){
                if(Math.random()<0.5){
                  val=8
                }else{
                  val=5
                }
              }
              //Layer of dirt.
              if(surface-5<y&&y<surface-1){val=5}
              //Layer of grass.
              if(surface-1<y&&y<surface){val=6}
              //Bushes.
              if(surface<y&&y<surface+1&&Math.random()<0.05){val=4}
              //Top leaves.
              if(surface+5<y&&y<surface+20&&Math.random()<0.5){val=4}
              save(w+"x"+x+"y"+y+"z"+z,val)
              //Trees.
              if(surface-1<y&&y<surface&&Math.random()<0.02){
                for(i=0;i<15;i++){
                  y2=y+i
                  save(w+"x"+eval(x+1)+"y"+y2+"z"+z,7)
                  save(w+"x"+eval(x-1)+"y"+y2+"z"+z,7)
                  save(w+"x"+x+"y"+y2+"z"+eval(z+1),7)
                  save(w+"x"+x+"y"+y2+"z"+eval(z-1),7)
                }
              }
            }else{
              //If a block has been cleared.
              if(read(w+"x"+x+"y"+y+"z"+z)==0){
                if(check_object(x,y,z)){
                  i1=check_id(x,y,z)
                  scene.remove(cube[i1])
                  delete cube[i1]
                }
              }
              //If is data into the database and there is not blocks.
              if(read(w+"x"+x+"y"+y+"z"+z)==1){
                if(!check_object(x,y,z)){
                  g(x,y,z,"box")
                }
              }
              if(read(w+"x"+x+"y"+y+"z"+z)==2){
                if(!check_object(x,y,z)){
                  g(x,y,z,"brick")
                }
              }
              if(read(w+"x"+x+"y"+y+"z"+z)==3){
                if(!check_object(x,y,z)){
                  g(x,y,z,"stone")
                }
              }
              if(read(w+"x"+x+"y"+y+"z"+z)==4){
                if(!check_object(x,y,z)){
                  g(x,y,z,"leaves")
                }
              }
              if(read(w+"x"+x+"y"+y+"z"+z)==5){
                if(!check_object(x,y,z)){
                  g(x,y,z,"dirt")
              }
              }
              if(read(w+"x"+x+"y"+y+"z"+z)==6){
                if(!check_object(x,y,z)){
                  g(x,y,z,"grass")
                }
              }
              if(read(w+"x"+x+"y"+y+"z"+z)==7){
                if(!check_object(x,y,z)){
                  g(x,y,z,"trunk")
                }
              }
              if(read(w+"x"+x+"y"+y+"z"+z)==8){
                if(!check_object(x,y,z)){
                  g(x,y,z,"limestone")
                }
              }
              if(read(w+"x"+x+"y"+y+"z"+z)==9){
                if(!check_object(x,y,z)){
                  g(x,y,z,"granite")
                }
              }
              if(read(w+"x"+x+"y"+y+"z"+z)==10){
                if(!check_object(x,y,z)){
                  g(x,y,z,"magma")
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
      for(i1 in cube){
        //Make all use shadow.
        cube[i1].castShadow=true
        cube[i1].receiveShadow=true
        //If it are blocks outer the render distance.
        if(
          check_into_square(fixed_x,fixed_y,fixed_z,cube[i1].position.x,cube[i1].position.y,cube[i1].position.z,render_distance+1000)
          &&
          !(check_into_square(fixed_x,fixed_y,fixed_z,cube[i1].position.x,cube[i1].position.y,cube[i1].position.z,render_distance/2))
        ){
          scene.remove(cube[i1])
          delete cube[i1]
        }
      }
    },200)
    
    read=(obj)=>{
      // Read.
      return localStorage.getItem(obj)
    }
    
    save=(obj,val)=>{
      // Save.
      localStorage.setItem(obj,val)
    }
    </script>
```

So... when I execute this, why the script is rendering too slow? I know that's hard but please help me. I heared about voxel.js but it doesn't load on my computer. Yes, I also use localStorage for storing the cubes into the store memory. Can anybody help me? Thanks for helping anyway.

Comment: You probably need to chunk your cubes into larger pieces of geometry by combining them into larger vertex buffers

Comment: I don't know how. I tried to use mergeMesh and it didn't worked.

Comment: You might find [this article](https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/lessons/threejs-voxel-geometry.html) useful

Answer (score 1):

Hard to say why merging meshes didn't work for you.

What you are doing now with individual cubes like you are doing means you can get max around 100 cubes before things will be very slow. To speed it up, you need to do a number of things.

First.. make all the cubes use the same texture, by combining all your textures into one BIG texture.. called a texture atlas.. then use the UVs of each cube to determine which part of the texture atlas they will render. You'll then need to combine each 32x32x32 chunk of cubes, into a single mesh. This way you are rendering 32,768 cubes as one mesh, with 1 drawcall.  The tradeoff is that to change one cube, you will need to rebuild one entire chunk of 32x32x32.. so you will have to make that super efficient.

This will get you a huge speed increase.

Next, you will need to set ".matrixAutoUpdate = false" on each chunk mesh, after calling mesh.updateMatrixWorld() when you first create it. This tells THREEJS that you will not be moving that chunk every frame, so it can skip some matrix calculations on each chunk.

This is a potentially huge speed boost.

From there.. you may also want to explore "instancing" which can let you draw a cube with a single number for cube type, per cube. This can give you another factor of 10 speed increase.

Here is my take on a minecraft kind of viewer i did for fun. It's not the most optimal code but it does do chunking and texture atlassing if I recall correctly, although I wrote it a while ago.. so my memory is hazy:

http://vectorslave.com/minecraft-viewer-thrax/index.html